# Change email message in forgot password

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0

By default joomla 3.0 sends an activation code in the email message, is it possible to configure for doing it by a link instead of copy and paste this code?

Answer (score 0):

The link should be made clickable by the email client. If not, the link might be missing the leading 'http://'.

You can edit the language file language/en-GB/en-GB.com_users.ini

```
COM_USERS_EMAIL_REGISTERED_WITH_ACTIVATION_BODY="Hello %s,\n\nThank you for registering at %s. Your account is created and must be activated before you can use it.\nTo activate the account click on the following link or copy-paste it in your browser:\nhttp://%s \n\nAfter activation you may login to %s using the following username and password:\n\nUsername: %s\nPassword: %s"
COM_USERS_EMAIL_REGISTERED_WITH_ACTIVATION_BODY_NOPW="Hello %s,\n\nThank you for registering at %s. Your account is created and must be activated before you can use it.\nTo activate the account click on the following link or copy-paste it in your browser:\nhttp://%s \n\nAfter activation you may login to %s using the following username and the password you entered during registration:\n\nUsername: %s"
```

or - better - put those lines into an override file (language/override/en-GB.override.ini).

Answer (score 0):

Nibra is correct, but to avoid creating a potentially malformed language file. I would strongly recommend using the built-in language over-ride that has been available since the 1.6 release.

Select `Extensions>>Language Manager>>Overrides` then click on the **New** button.

In that screen you can search for either the text you want to change "Thank you for registering" or the language tokens like:

- `COM_USERS_EMAIL_REGISTERED_WITH_ACTIVATION_BODY`
- `COM_USERS_EMAIL_REGISTERED_WITH_ACTIVATION_BODY_NOPW`

The best thing about language overrides mechanism is that when 3.1, or any later version, is released you can upgrade safely and not have to worry about the changes you've made being overwritten by any updates.